# Почему Spring не создает бин HibernateTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

Есть прстое хранилище которое должно использовать `HibernateTemplate` для сохранения данных в таблицу. Но Spring не создает его `bean` отказываясь автоматически подтягивать `HibernateTemplate`. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться как это поправить.

Вот такая ошибка:

> [main] WARN
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext -
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'HItemStorage' defined in file
>   [/Users/pavel/GitHub/Spring-data-Hibernate/target/classes/ru/pravvich/HItemStorage.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {}
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'HItemStorage' defined in file
>   [/Users/pavel/GitHub/Spring-data-Hibernate/target/classes/ru/pravvich/HItemStorage.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {}

```
@Component
public class HItemStorage implements Storage {

    private final HibernateTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public HItemStorage(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> getAll() {
        return (List<Item>) template.find("from Item");
    }
    ...
}
```

Используется вот такой конфигурационный файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Database properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/spring_jdbc" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Connecting template -->
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>ru/pravvich/Item.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.pravvich" />

</beans>
```

Получается прописанный `class="...LocalSessionFactoryBean"` не срабатывает?

Падает при

```
final ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("hibernate-context.xml");
```

Даже не доходит до:

```
HItemStorage storage = context.getBean(HItemStorage.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так template бин у вас имеет класс LocalSessionFactoryBean, а спринг вытается найти бин template с классом HibernateTemplate

судя по этому посту :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780585/creating-hibernatetemplate-by-org-springframework-orm-hibernate4-localsessionfac

Использовать HibernateTemplate не рекомендуется с 3,0,1 версии. И там же предлагают использовать SessionFactoryImpl

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'sessionFactory' must be of type [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean], but was actually of type [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl]
```